# With Rhino Mocks how to stub a method that makes use of the params keyword?

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks, stub, rhino-mocks-3.5

I am attempting to setup an expectation on a repository. The method makes use of the [params keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
string GetById(int key, params string[] args);
```

The expectation I have setup:

```
var resourceRepo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IResourceRepository>();
resourceRepo.Expect(r => r.GetById(
    Arg<int>.Is.Equal(123),
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("Name"),
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("Super"),
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("Mario"),
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("No"),
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("Yes"),
    Arg<string>.Is.Equal("Maybe")))
    .Return(String.Empty);
```

throws this exception:

> Test method
>   XYZ threw exception:  System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Use Arg ONLY within a mock method call while recording. 2 arguments expected, 7
>   have been defined.

What is wrong with the setup of my expectation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

params is just an array:

```
var resourceRepo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IResourceRepository>();
resourceRepo
  .Expect(r => r.GetById(
    Arg<int>.Is.Equal(123),
    Arg<string[]>.List.ContainsAll(new[]
                                   {
                                       "Name",
                                       "Super",
                                       "Mario",
                                       "No",
                                       "Yes",
                                       "Maybe"
                                   })))
  .Return(String.Empty);
```

Comment: Agreed, frustratingly Visual Studio was given me an error when I tried this yesterday. I didn't however actually build the app so the "error" was the IDE "losing its mind." #sigh

I made a minor modification to your answer as `ContainsAll` requires an IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: @ahsteele. Right, it requires an array. Would have been nice to have params there ...

Comment: I think the correct answer would be to use `.Equal` instead of `.ContainsAll` there. Contains is not restrictive enough, since it would pass if more things were provided in the original call.

Comment: @julealgon: the question is about the syntax, not about details of the test. Take my code with ContainsAll as an example to write your own test according to your needs.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I thought you were writing his test in the correct form (still seems like it), in which case `Equal` would have to be used.

Comment: I've just come to find this post after having this issue. I came up with a similar solution - except I used a home grown 'SequenceEqual'. HOWEVER I now want to be able to say that say the 1st and 3rd arguments equal x and y, but I don't care what the second argument equals. Any pointers?